# Get points from Multiple sites in one call

Tags: support, api-v2.1, sites

Is there any way to get total points and badges from various sites (e.g. stackoverflow, sharepoint, wordpress etc.) in one call?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about these numbers for a particular user, you can use the [`/users/{id}/associated` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) with the given user's network ID to get these values for each of the sites the user is a member of.

You can selectively filter through the results to pick out the sites that you're interested in.